# iText generated dynamic pdf printing blank page

Tags: java, pdf, printing, itext, dynamicpdf

I have a dynamic pdf form , which is filled programatically from xml input data by using iText APIs. But when we print the filled dynamic pdf form,  blank page is printed. If we open and save the output pdf and then print, its working fine.

Can anybody help why would be the reason for blank page and how this issue can be resolved?

My form filling code:

```
PdfReader reader=new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,new FileOutputStream(dest),'\0', true);
PdfWriter writer=stamper.getWriter();
File file = new File(src);
String fileName=file.getName();
PdfAction action = null;
action = PdfAction.javaScript(readJsFileTostring(jsFileName), writer);
writer.setOpenAction(action);
stamper.setPageAction(PdfWriter.PAGE_OPEN, action, 1);
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
XfaForm xfa = form.getXfa();
xfa.fillXfaForm(new FileInputStream(xmlData));
stamper.close();
```

I use Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 2018.009.20050 to print the form.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: where is your source code?

Comment: The issue is with dynamic pdf form which is printing blank page.

Comment: there is only two ways, either people watch and understand your code and *provide you a solution* or simple provide you a url example from the web but there are conditions.

Comment: *"why would be the reason for blank page and how this issue can be resolved?"* - with the little information you give one can diagnose: There may be a bug in your code or in your pdf or in iText or in Adobe reader. The issue can be resolved by fixing the bug in question.

Comment: @mkl , I have a dynamic pdf (XFA form) template which is filled programatically using iText and filled pdf form looks good. When I try to print the filled pdf form, blank page is getting printed. If I save the filled pdf output (file -->Save As) , print works fine.Hope you understand my question.

Comment: XFA Forms are **not** PDF. They are XML forms with a PDF wrapped round them. THe PDF portion of an XFA form usually contains just enough information to say something like 'your viewer does not understand this format'. You have not said how you are printing the file. If you are sending it direct to a printer which can print PDF, then it will (in general) print the PDF, but not the XFA. So it sounds to me like the PDF portion of the form is simply blank. Basically, XFA is a really bad idea, and its been dropped from PDF 2.0.

Comment: Ann, I understand your question. But apparently you did not understand @Arif's and my comments: without your code (of filling in the pdf with iText) and pdf file, we cannot help you. KenS' comment might or might not point to the issue. Probably not as you don't say you cannot print XFA forms in general but merely those filled in using iText. But please also indicate from which programs you try to print the form.

Comment: @mkl  I do not use any program to print the generated pdf file, I open the filled pdf and do a Ctrl+P or File-->Print and which produces blank page.

Comment: If you *"open the filled pdf and do a Ctrl+P"* for printing, you *do* use a program for printing: the program you opened the pdf with! So which program do you open it with?

Comment: @mkl I use Adobe Acrobat Reader18 to open the filled pdf file

Comment: Ok. Now please the remaining data mentioned above: (a shortened version of) the code you use to fill the form and the form itself, optionally also a filled version of the form.

Comment: @mkl PdfReader reader=new PdfReader(src); PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,new FileOutputStream(dest),'\0', true);   
PdfWriter writer=stamper.getWriter();File file = new File(src);
String fileName=file.getName(); 
PdfAction action = null;
action = PdfAction.javaScript(readJsFileTostring(jsFileName), writer);
writer.setOpenAction(action);  
stamper.setPageAction(PdfWriter.PAGE_OPEN, action, 1);AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();  
XfaForm xfa = form.getXfa();
xfa.fillXfaForm(new FileInputStream(xmlData));stamper.close();

Comment: Ok. (It would have been better to edit the code into the question but at least it is here now.) Now the form itself, optionally also a filled version of the form.

Comment: That being said... Are you sure you are using "Adobe Acrobat Reader18" for opening and printing the file? I'm not aware of that Reader version...

Comment: @mkl the version is Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 2018.009.20050

Comment: Ok.Now the form itself, optionally also a filled version of the form.

Comment: @mkl thanks for the help, the issue is resolved by a small change in the javascript file which is embedded in the xfa form. The < in the for loop is replaced by &lt; and print worked fine. Thanks again.

Comment: In that case please either make that an actual answer you can accept (by clicking the tick at its upper left) after a short time, or else remove this question.